# Encrypt the text of a PDF file with the read only availability

Tags: pdf, encryption

How can I encrypt the text of my PDF to prevent normal softwares from extracting the text from it?

I tried using Adobe Reader DC to disable the copy option but some websites like https://smallseotools.com/ still manage to extract the text from the PDF easily.

I know that there is no perfect solution to prevent people from using an OCR or something similar, I just want to stop bots from extracting the text.

Comment: Why don't you just encrypt the entire file? If you don't want things on the internet to read your file, then it shouldn't be publicly accessible.

Comment: As I said I want people to be able to read it and I don't mind if some of them use an OCR software to extract the text, I just want my text to be unreadable by bots.